# I have SQL server name and DTS packages name. How can I view it in SQL Server Managment Studio 2012?

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012, ssms, dts, ssms-2012

I need to know, where I can see these packages under SSMS 2012 while connecting to server where DTS packages are actually stored.

As this is first time I am going to play around DTS packages so not sure what server type (databse engine, integration serve etc) I need to select while connecting.

Comment: So you are connecting to a SQL 2000 Server? Do you mean DTS or SSIS? There is a big difference

Comment: Yes I have name of DTS packages only not SSIS. Now I am clueless where to find these packages after connecting it to Server. As this is first time I am going to play around DTS packages so not sure what server type (databse engine, integration serve etc) I need to select while connecting.

Comment: This link (the first that came up when I searched) describes how to view them in SQL 2008 R2 SSMS. You might need to install that. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645945(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: I'm going to ask again so begging your pardon but are you talking about DTS, which was what we built in SQL Server 2000 and used Enterprise Manager/Query Analyzer to interact with, or DTSX aka SSIS which is new with 2005. Your question tags seem conflicted.

Comment: If you are going with DTS, why? That product is dead, amazingly dead. They took out support within SSIS after 2008 for DTS and even then it was a bit of a bear to get it working (separate install). What compelling business reason do you have to push so much risk onto your client by using a dated, unsupported technology?

Comment: Exactly you are right, I just wanted to view legacy DTS package in SSMS 2012 then I will rewrite my new SSIS packages. But problem is that I am not able to view DTS packages in SSMS 2012.  @Nick.McDermaid your link is good but I am expecting the same reference for 2012 version.

Comment: I'm fairly certain the functionality doesn't exist in 2012